# SaveChanges() in Entity Framework consumes 30% CPU

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I need to copy data from old tables in the database to new tables using Entity Framework (I can't do that in SQL) but it is very slow.
How can I speed it up?

As I checked the method `SaveChanges()` consumes 30% CPU - strange. Maybe instead of saving related entities as: `X.File = userFile` - I should write: `X.FileId = userFile.Id`?

```
private void CopyFile(FileFromForm oldFileFromForm)
{
    using (var transaction = _dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        var userSheetsRelatedWithForm = _dbContext.UserRelatedwithForm.AsNoTracking()
                    .Include(x => x.Sheet)
                    .Where(x => x.FormId == oldFileFromForm.FormId)
                    .ToList();

        UserFiles userFile = new UserFiles();
        newCandidateFile.CandidateId = userSheetsRelatedWithForm.First().UserId; 
        newCandidateFile.FileFormatId = 1;
        newCandidateFile.FileTypeId = 2;
        newCandidateFile.CompanyId = oldFileFromForm.CompanyId; 
        newCandidateFile.FileName = oldFileFromForm.FileName;                
        _dbContext.UserFiles.Add(userFile);

        FormFiles formFile = new FormFiles();
        formFile.FormId = oldFileFromForm.FormId;
        formFile.File = userFile; // Can it be: formFile.FileId = userFile.Id ?
        _dbContext.FormFiles.Add(formFile);

        foreach (var sheetId in userSheetsRelatedWithForm.Select(x => x.SheetId).Distinct())
        {
            UserFilesWithSheets userFilesWithSheet = new UserFilesWithSheets();
            userFilesWithSheet.SheetId = sheetId;
            userFilesWithSheet.File = userFile; // Can it be: userFilesWithSheet.FileId = userFile.Id ?
            _dbContext.UserFilesWithSheets.Add(userFilesWithSheet);
        }

        _dbContext.SaveChanges(); // It consumes 30% CPU !!!
        transaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: you can make stored procedure in sql and call it using Entity framework

Comment: SQlBulkCopy should be the better approach - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Do you know how many entities you are saving in your transaction ?

Comment: Minimum 3 entities.